# Unable to run Peer in Libp2p Rust implementation

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio, libp2p

Trying out the default Ping example using Libp2p rust.
Rust version: 1.70.0
System windows 10

```
use futures::prelude::*;
use libp2p::{noise, ping, swarm::SwarmEvent, tcp, yamux, Multiaddr};
use std::{error::Error, time::Duration};
use tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let _ = tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_env_filter(EnvFilter::from_default_env())
        .try_init();

    let mut swarm = libp2p::SwarmBuilder::with_new_identity()
        .with_tokio()
        .with_tcp(
            tcp::Config::default(),
            noise::Config::new,
            yamux::Config::default,
        )?
        .with_behaviour(|_| ping::Behaviour::default())?
        .with_swarm_config(|cfg| cfg.with_idle_connection_timeout(Duration::from_secs(u64::MAX)))
        .build();


    swarm.listen_on("/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/0".parse()?)?;


    if let Some(addr) = std::env::args().nth(1) {
        let remote: Multiaddr = addr.parse()?;
        swarm.dial(remote)?;
        println!("Dialed {addr}")
    }

    loop {
        match swarm.select_next_some().await {
            SwarmEvent::NewListenAddr { address, .. } => println!("Listening on {address:?}"),
            SwarmEvent::Behaviour(event) => println!("{event:?}"),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

I run the first peer using cargo run and get output in terminal:
`Listening on "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/65332"`

But on the running the other peer in another terminal using the command:
`cargo run /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/65332`

it doesn't run and provides the following output:
 `Running target\debug\p2pRecipe.exe C:/Program Files/Git/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/65332   Error: InvalidMultiaddr error: process didn't exit successfully: target\debug\p2pRecipe.exe C:/Program Files/Git/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/65332' (exit code: 1)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvL4e.jpg)

Not sure what the issue is.
It might be a system issue. I've seen many tutorials and articles running the same code and they've been able to run it successfully

**Update**

Meanwhile I was trying the debug(just added a few println statements) and now on running the second peer this is what pops up

`error: linking with link.exe failed: exit code: 1104`

`note: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\VSCode Rust\p2pRecipe\target\debug\deps\p2pRecipe.exe'`

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided here works for me on Windows, as you alluded. I'm running it with Rust 1.76 though, so you might have more success with a higher version of Rust. You can update it with `rustup update`.

If that doesn't work, it can be related to a network issue on your machine. That's going to be harder to find. I was also not able to reproduce your error. The first time running it (on Windows 11) I did get a message that required me to allow the program to run, so you might need to do that again. Resetting your network connection can also help (restart your pc if you haven't already tried that).

Comment: Thank you for replying
I'll update my rust today and get back here.
There was a permission request the first time I ran it as well.But not sure how to get that request again.
I've added some more details here

Comment: Deleting your target folder might be necessary as well (or just run cargo clean). The update might've caused that error. As to the InvalidMultiaddr problem, I'll need to check the source code more in depth. Maybe a an extra space or so caused a parse error or something similar?

Comment: And I just found a similar issue btw: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/108525, so that will probably help you solve the linking error you had.